# Table Command with multiple Variables

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, eigenvalues

I am new to Mathematica, so I'm not sure about the ins and outs of what's possible and what is not.

I am trying to view the eigenvalues of multiple matrices at once. In particular, this matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for $\{ a,b,c\} \in \{ -1,0,1 \}$

---

I have been able to do this for a significantly simpler example:

$\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

by doing the following:

```
L = Table[{{{a, 1}, {1, 0}}}, {a, -1, 1, 1}]

H = Eigenvalues /@ L
```

Of course, I'm not sure if this the best way to do this in this case, and from what I've tried, this doesn't seem to be an easy thing to do to grow this for bigger matrices or more variables.

---

So back to where I'm stuck - I've tried starting off with:

```
L = Table[{{a, b, c}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {a, -1, 1, 1}, {b, -1, 1,
1}, {c, -1, 1, 1}]

H = Eigenvalues /@ L
```

This doesn't work; particularly, it throws up a list of vectors, saying they're at position 1 and is not a non-empty square matrix.

So how would I go about doing this? And is it suitable for being able to easily expand it to bigger matrices / more variables?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `Eigenvalues /@ Flatten[L, 2]`. Notice that your `Table` expression made a nested list of matrices, not a flat one (check `Dimensions[L]`). You need to flatten it to a list of 27 $3\times 3$ matrices instead.

Comment: You can also do (1) `H = Map[Eigenvalues, L, {3}];` or (2) `H2 = Table[
  Eigenvalues@{{a, b, c}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {a, -1, 1, 
   1}, {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -1, 1, 1}]`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers; both are extremely useful! :)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that your `Table` expression made a nested list of matrices, not a flat one (check `Dimensions[L]`). You need to flatten it to a list of 27 3×3 matrices instead, so  you could use `Eigenvalues /@ Flatten[L, 2]`.

However, an alternative method to make your matrices is the following:

```
Lnew = Join[{#}, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}] & /@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}];
Dimensions[Lnew]

(* {27, 3, 3} *)
```

Then `Eigenvalues /@ Lnew` will work directly

Answer (score 2):

```
L2 = {#, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}]
Dimensions[L2]
```

> {27, 3, 3}

```
Eigenvalues /@ L2
```

> {{-1, 0, 0}, {Root[-1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[-1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[-1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}, {-1 + I, -1 - I, 
>     1}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 0}, {-1, -1, 
>     1}, {Root[-2 - #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[-2 - #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[-2 - #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}, {-2, 1, 
>     0}, {Root[-1 - 2 #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
>     Root[-1 - 2 #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[-1 - 2 #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[
>     2], -1}, {-1, (-1)^(1/3), -(-1)^(2/3)}, {0, 0, 
>     0}, {1, -(-1)^(1/3), (-1)^(2/3)}, {Root[1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 1], 
>     Root[1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 3], Root[1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 2]}, {-1, 1, 
>     0}, {Root[-1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 1], Root[-1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[-1 - #1 + #1^3 &, 2]}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1, 
>     1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 0}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), -1,
>      1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, {1 + I, 
>     1 - I, -1}, {Root[1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], Root[1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2],
>      Root[1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}, {1, 0, 
>     0}, {Root[2 - #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[2 - #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[2 - #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), 
>     1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 0}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 
>     1}, {Root[1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>     Root[1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
>     Root[1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]}, {2, -1, 0}}

You can also work with `L` to get an 3X3X3 array of eigenvalues as follows:

```
H1 = Map[Eigenvalues, L, {3}]; 
H2 = Table[Eigenvalues@{{a, b, c}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {a, -1, 1, 1}, 
 {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -1, 1, 1}];
H3 = Outer[Eigenvalues[{{##}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}] &,
  {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}];
H1 == H2 == H3
```

> True